# pull data from SQL Server and display in a normal sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, bcs, external-contenttype

i'm working on project where i have to pull data from SQL Server and display in a list. But  i can only display in a external list not in a normal sharepoint list. Is there any way? Or work aorund to get all the features which we get in normal list can be applied on external list. I have searched a lot but no success!

Comment: Short Answer: No. User an external list via BCS and you won't get Workflows etc.

Comment: Which particular feature do you need on your external list ?

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to reflect the data from SQL Server or Insert data from SQL Server into a SharePoint list?

Comment: You can try converting the External List into a normal sharepoint list. Check out the link below. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559346.aspx